# How to compile a .py file which has a .kv file and other resource files

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have written an application in python and Kivy and it has a main.py and main.kv file and also other resource files like image and text file. When i compile them with PyInstaller.exe on windows 7 i dont know what goes on in the background. The .exe file crashes with different errors each time i compile.

So i wanted someone to shed some light on how i will get all the files in my main.py i.e image & text files compiled.

The command which i tried in commandline is:

```
PyInstaller.exe --onefile --icon=myicon.png main.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you ran `Pyinstaller` for the first time, it should have created a `main.spec` file. You can edit the `main.spec` file to add any additional resources that your app requires (in addition to what `Pyinstaller` detects). Then you can run `Pyinstaller` with the simple command:

```
pyinstaller main.spec
```

Note that most of the options to `Pyinstaller` have no effect when you provide a spec file argument (all that info should be in the spec file). For more information see [Pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: i get this error "OSError: File C:\Users\Sycopath\Desktop\Test field\backup\bk1\dist\Njoro\kivymd \fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttfs not found. When i execute my code it works perfectly. and the path of the .ttfs does not exist

Comment: If your script requires files that PyInstaller does not know about, do this "pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir --paths=/path/to/otherdir myscript.py"

Comment: Are you getting that error when running `pyinstaller`? Is that path referenced in your code or in your `main.spec` file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Ikolim where should i get the documentation of the "pyi-makespec..." to avoid further questions

Comment: I get the error while running the .exe after compiling. The error arises from kivymd design module and i did not use the .spec file. i just used the "python -m PyInstaller..." from the commandprompt

Comment: The documentation for `pyi-makespec` is part of the documentation that I referenced above.